# ArrayApend on Multidimensional Array - Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Is there a way to append data to a 3D array with arrayAppend? I am trying to create a shopping cart and I need to add each item with quantity, price, and shipping location together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D array?  It may be easier to have an array of struct's.

```
cart = [
  {
    qty: 2,
    price: 3.99,
    shippingLocation: "somewhere"
  }
];

arrayAppend(cart, {
    qty: 3,
    price: 19.99,
    shippingLocation: "somewhere else"
});
```

Comment: `arrayAppend()`, Henry, not `structAppend()`.

Comment: @Geo, if you find an error with this, follow Adam's advice, Henry made an easy mistake, with a very easy fix.

Comment: @cfqueryparam thanks. I figured as much when I started working on it. Thanks to Adam as well